# How to open and view CGNS files on Windows 10 after installing PyCGNS python package?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, pyqt5, cgns

After installing PyCGNS python package from Anaconda distribution, I am not able to open CGNS files as recommended in the following pages using the command line `CGNS.NAV` or `cg_look`:

[Browsing your CGNS tree with NAV](https://pycgns.github.io/introduction.html)

Here is the error message I am receiving whether I am running the command line in Git Bash, Powershels, or CMD:

```
CGNS.NAV: FATAL error, cannot import qtpy.QtCore...
```

---

Hints:

1. pyqt5 is already installed
2. print(sys.path)

```
'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\Scripts', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python38.zi
p', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\DLLs', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\
ProgramData\\Anaconda3', '', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages', '
C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\vboxapi-1.0-py3.8.egg', 'C:\\Pro
gramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\li
b\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\
Pythonwin', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions
', 'C:\\Users\\user_name\\.ipython']
```

Comment: `import qtpy.QtCore` looks wrong. It should be `pyqt5.QtCore`

Comment: Thanks bfris, does that mean that I need to modify the source code for the PyCGNS?

Comment: Huh. That comes from PyCGNS? I found [this](https://github.com/pyCGNS/pyCGNS/issues/125) on their github site. Looks like you also need to install QtPy which is "... a small abstraction layer that lets you write applications using a single API call to either PyQt or PySide"

Comment: After following that suggestion and reinstalling it again, cg_look is working but CGNS.NAV not. Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install PyQT.
Open the cmd.exe prompt from the anaconda navigator (in the home menu).

Execute this command:

`conda install pyqt5`

If you already had install it, maybe it's not in your enviroment.

Please post the output from:

```py
print(sys.path)
```

Find out where PyQt5 is installed and ad it to your path-enviroment. You will find plenty of howto's in the internet. Here is one of them (Source: https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-add-python-to-path-variable-in-windows):

```
Right-clicking This PC and going to Properties.

Clicking on the Advanced system settings in the menu on the left.

Clicking on the Environment Variables button o​n the bottom right.

In the System variables section, selecting the Path variable and clicking on Edit. The next screen will show all the directories that are currently a part of the PATH variable.

Clicking on New and entering Python’s install directory.
```

Comment: Just added that to the question.

Comment: Did you install pyqt5?

Comment: Yes, I checked it. It's already installed.

Comment: Find out where PyQT5 is installed. Most likely in your python lib path. (Maybe: C:\Python\lib\site-packages\PyQt5). You can use windows search. If you got the path, use this instruction to add the path in your path-enviroment. https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-add-python-to-path-variable-in-windows

Comment: /c/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/tf/Lib/site-packages/PyQt5 and /c/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/tf/sip/PyQt5. What is the difference between the two? Which one should be placed in the path-environment?

Comment: Add both. For further information about sip: https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5-sip/4.19.19/

Comment: Thank you Robni, I have to wait for the admin to do that for me. I will get back to you in case things are not working.

Comment: No problem. But here at SO, we don't wrote "thank you", instead we mark the question as useful and/or as accepted. If you need further assistance, just ask.

Comment: I cannot vote due to not reaching the total rank of 15. However, I guess I can accept the answer and I will do so once I verified things are working correctly.